# jQuery dynamic ajax data with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hey all i am trying to figure out why, when i populate my page with data, when i try to do a .click event on a checkbox that it never finds it... **but** when i have the code on the page without being gathered from ajax it works just fine?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   jQuery('#selectAll').click(function () {
       console.log('hit');
   });
});

<th scope="col" id="cb" class="manage-column column-cb check-column">
    <input id="selectAll" type="checkbox">
</th>
```

The above code works just fine if the checkbox code is on the page to start with **but does not work** if the same code is populated via **ajax**.

What would i be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use on delegated event

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(document).on('click','#selectAll',function () {
     console.log('hit');
  });
});
```

you need to delegate the event if the element is generated dynamically... however, it is recommended to delegate it to the closest staic parent container than the `document` itself for better performance.. [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about on delegated events